# Autoplaying and looping embedded videos doesn't work with sound

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to embed youtube video with autoplay, Loop, unmute. But Sound always mute when we use it with autoplay & loop.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k6VjkfdKwFo?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=k6VjkfdKwFo"  width="560" height="315"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This is a requirement of modern browsers. For video content to autoplay it has to be muted.

Comment: ok.
have you any solution of this issue?

Comment: The solution is to mute the video, which is what is happening. There is no alternative.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciated it.